# PhpStorm new tag instead of new line

Tags: tags, phpstorm

I've got a problem with php storm. Every time I press `Enter` after a word, PhpStorm makes up a tag instead of a new line as you can see here:

[image]

Do you know where I can disable this function?

Comment: Please check your Emmet settings (expand key) -- `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Emmet` -- you may have `Enter` as expand key -- use more traditional `Tab` or something else instead.

Comment: Awesome, that worked... Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check your Emmet settings (expand key) -- you may have <kbd>Enter</kbd> as expand key -- use more traditional <kbd>Tab</kbd> or something else instead.

**Settings/Preferences | Editor | Emmet**

[image]